# Grails : Undeploy on Glassfish causes connection pool to be no more usable

Tags: java, grails, jdbc, glassfish, connection-pooling

I'm working on a **grails 2.2.1** project running on **glassfish 3.1.2.2**, using a jndi pooled datasource connected to a **postgres 9.2** database. 
When I deploy for the first time the application, I have no issues, everything works fine.

But, everytime I undeploy (or redeploy) my application, my connection pool stops working. 
If I try to ping using glassfish admin console, I get this error :

```
Avertissement: RAR8054: Exception while creating an unpooled [test] connection for pool [ sample ],
Connection could not be allocated because: No suitable driver found for
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sample?loginTimeout=0&socketTimeout=0&prepareThreshold=5&unknownLength=2147483647&loglevel=0&tcpkeepalive=false
Grave: RestResponse.getResponse() donne FAILURE.
endpoint = http://localhost:4848/management/domain/resources/ping-connection-pool.json ; attrs = {id=sample}'
```

I repeat : my connection pool works fine when I deploy (I have the postgresql driver in "/glassfish/lib", my connection pool is correctly configured, etc.), it's only when I undeploy that I have troubles. 
This bug is highly reproductible, I even did a small grails project that reproduces the problem, you only need to have to configure a jndi datasource connected to a "sample" database (jndi/sample) on your glassfish server.

Here is the github link :
**https://github.com/fabier/GlassfishJDBCGrailsPostgresql**
And the war :
**https://www.dropbox.com/s/cb9hmgc6lfabl5x/GlassfishJDBCGrailsPostgresql-0.1.war**
and the domains.xml file:
**https://www.dropbox.com/s/ljealpfp0zxj2r4/domain.xml**

On grails side, my connection to the pool is configured this way:

```
environments {
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop"
            jndiName = "jdbc/sample"
        }
    }
}
```

I think this bug is severe, since it kills a connection pool that can be shared amongst other webapps or ears. 
For information, I did a bit of research, sensing it might be some sort of class unloader associated with undeployment, I found log4j that could be linked to this problem, so I tryed :

```
-Dorg.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES=false
```

but it didn't help.

Last point : in fact, postgresql driver is fully unloaded, so that other connection pools using postgresql driver are not usable after an undeploy.

Link to same issue in Grails mailing List:
http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Undeploy-on-Glassfish-causes-connection-pool-to-be-no-more-usable-td4643041.html
Link to same issue in Glassfish's Jira:
http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20094

Thanks for your help.